# How to use Shared preference in Handler android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using this code to save string:

```
    public class MySharedPref {
    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "TripDetails";
    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private Editor prefsEditor;

    public MySharedPref(Context activity) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    }

    public String getPrefsValue(String value) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getString(value, "");
    }

    public void savePrefsValue(String key, String Value) {
        prefsEditor.putString(key, Value);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getImei(String value) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getString(value, "");
    }

    public void saveImei(String key, String Value) {
        prefsEditor.putString(key, Value);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public Boolean checkKey(String Key) {
        if (appSharedPrefs.contains(Key))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

and calling with:

```
MySharedPref mySharedPref = new MySharedPref(context);
mySharedPref.saveImei("Imei", Imei);
```

but within a handler. I am getting **null pointer Exception**.
I am not getting the reason, Why it is so. Please Help.

**logcat:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 11:46:52.213: W/System.err(17575):    at com.example.util.MySharedPref.<init>(MySharedPref.java:14)
09-15 11:46:52.215: W/System.err(17575):    at com.example.util.SerialRecieveThread.handleWaitBuffer(SerialThread.java:273)
09-15 11:46:52.216: W/System.err(17575):    at com.example.util.SerialRecieveThread.step(SerialThread.java:612)
09-15 11:46:52.219: W/System.err(17575):    at com.example.util.SerialRecieveThread.run(SerialThread.java:172)
09-15 11:46:52.220: W/System.err(17575):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Probably `context` is `null`

Comment: I have use activity but still getting the same exception . Any alternative way?

Comment: What is the exception you get add the stacktrace

Comment: Handler? what Handler?

Comment: Updated log-cat, Please have a look.

Comment: Where do you call this code?

Comment: I am calling this code in 
public class SerialThread implements Runnable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following way

**Step 1**

Create an Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

In Android Manifest file declare following

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">

</application>
```

**Step 3**

```
MySharedPref mySharedPref = new MySharedPref(MyApplication.getAppContext());
mySharedPref.saveImei("Imei", Imei);
```

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type LoginActivity is accessible in scope :(

Comment: @Developer try my edited answer. As you are using thread and then sharedpreferences, you need ApplicationContext instead of activity context

Comment: Its my pleasure to help... :)